# Sort Datatable in vb.net with linq by Column index

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq

I need to sort a datatable. I do it with linq this an example

```
Dim query = From c In dt.AsEnumerable _
              Order By c.Field(Of DateTime?)("LastPurchaseDate"), _
                       c.Field(Of String)("LastName") Descending
            Dim dv As DataView = query.AsDataView
```

But my problem is that i need to sort the fields not by passing the name of the column but the index of that. Is there a way?

Comment: well I have trouble with the name, because I am using Greek names and it sort of blowing the code up. When i use english it works fine

Comment: I am doing this also,  
Dim query = From c In dt.AsEnumerable _
Order By c.Field(Of String)(10) Ascending
Dim dv As DataView = query.AsDataView 
but it doesn't work it keeps the same sort, when I gather the dv.Table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim orderedby = From p As DataRow In dt.Rows Order By p.Item(0) Ascending, 
p.Item(1) Ascending 
Select p cast p as datarow
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally I managed to do this using clone method of a datatable.

```
    Dim DataTableNew As DataTable = New DataTable
    DataTableNew = dt.Clone
    Dim query = (From c In dt.AsEnumerable Order By c.Field(Of String)(12) Ascending)
    query.CopyToDataTable(DataTableNew, LoadOption.OverwriteChanges)
```